# Does (linux's) chrono::duration also include the time a thread is paused?

Tags: c++, multithreading, scheduling, c++-chrono

I am currently comparing speculative and non-speculative locking with Intel TSX and OpenMP in C++. The code is compiled with the Intel icpc compiler to the C++17-standard and run on linux.
I am comparing the execution times I measured with chrono::duration between different configurations. However my data has been very inconsistent between runs which lead me to reconsider my approach to measuring the execution time.
This is the relevant part of my code. When I enter the for-loop, the individual iterations of the loop are spread across multiple threads. If (some of) these threads get paused by the scheduler, maybe have to wait in line for a while before they get more CPU time, how is this handled? **Does the time chrono::duration measures also include the time while the thread is paused by the scheduler?**

```c++
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

omp_lock_t lock;
omp_init_lock_with_hint(&lock, omp_lock_hint_speculative);
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int j=0; j<iterations; j++)
{
    int a=std::rand()%array_size;     //pseudo-random array location
    omp_set_lock(&lock);
    numbers[a] = numbers[a] + 1;
    omp_unset_lock(&lock);
}

end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
cout << (end-start).count()
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

*Here's some more background to what results I got. I don't think it is strictly relevant to the question but perhaps it helps to understand what I mean.*

This result is fairly representative of the problems I faced:[image: Locking with 32 Threads] 
The trend is similar but the 'traditional' (i.e. non-speculative) locks are extremely inconsistent and much slower than the rest. What I would have expected, is the non-speculative locks to stay mostly the same, theoretically it is just as fast with a high probability of collisions as with a low one. There are some more inconsistencies with the baseline (no synchronisation constructs) sometimes being the slowest of the three and so forth. Clearly my test workload is not very sophisticated and perhaps I am grasping at straws here - but I have convinced myself that I might be able to explain this data better, if I had a better understanding of how chrono worked.

Comment: As you are using `std::chrono::system_clock` this measures real time wall clock.  _"...Class std::chrono::system_clock represents the system-wide real time wall clock...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock  `chrono::duration` is just a handy container for a time interval and it's value depends on which clock is used.

Comment: I don't see any C++ clock that holds just thread active time see - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono for a list of available clocks.

Comment: Why don't you use a profiler (such as Intel's VTune) to understand what is happening in your application?

Comment: Note that TSX has been disabled on many processors for security reasons (vulnerabilities) in a quite recent microcode update (few month ago). For example, this is the case on my i5-9600KF processor. You can check that for your processor at https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000059422/processors.html.